# Should obfuscated JavaScript be allowed?

Tags: discussion, policy

I had posted an ["obfuscated rickroll in Greasemonkey"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/365/obfuscated-rickroll-script) challenge, which I have deleted in response to Mike Bethany's comment that answers to the question would be of primary use to "spammers." In general, I feel that a primary issue is that of obfuscated JavaScript, so I would like the community's input.

**Why should we allow obfuscated JavaScript?** JavaScript is a programming language like any other, and code obfuscation is a valid and on-topic challenge on this site. Would we not allow obfuscated Python, Lua, or C#?

**Why should we not allow obfuscated JavaScript?** JavaScript is essential to many web browser [security exploits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_%28computer_security%29). It is already hard enough for antivirus software and firewalls to detect malicious payloads obfuscated using common, simple techniques; we shouldn't make it any harder by describing any "new" ways to obfuscate JavaScript code.

Which has more merit?

Comment: We shouldn't allow C either, it can access our hard disk!

Answer (score 27):

I don't believe in security by obscurity.

If the only way (we think) we keep web browsing safe is by "not disclosing" ways to make obfuscated JS, I dare say the black hats are quite a few steps ahead of us.

So, in my personal opinion, you should reopen your question. :-)

Answer (score 13):

isn't the point of code golf to solve in a few characters as possible?

If so, isn't obfuscation part of the game?

Comment: The original name of this proposal was "Code Golf & **Programming Puzzle** ".

Comment: @HoLyVieR so you are saying that it is also about puzzles? so? can you expand on your point?

Comment: Nevermind, I misread what you said.

Answer (score 6):

If you can run in a sand box, either one of your own or [one someone else maintains on the internet](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202/78), the question of malicious code becomes less of an issue (note I generally don't run anything from this site until I have a vague idea what it is up to).

Comment: The JavaScript sandbox is not impenetrable, as new security exploits are regularly discovered. In fact, Mozilla just released an update to Firefox to patch some holes. http://www.mozilla.org/security/announce/

Comment: @idealmachine: Of course. You're not going to be able to run unknown code with *no* risk.

Answer (score 4):

I think we should allow it. You can always run the code through [jsBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org), which unobfuscates the code.

Comment: Note that a beautifier will not de-obfuscate any code with any effort put into obfuscation at all. It can just do some basic pattern recognition and spaces.

Answer (score -2):

**PLEASE I'm begging you DON'T MAKE IT impossible for US LANGUAGE DESIGNERS OVER HERE not to osmotically acquire biases toward the PRIMARY-MAINSTREAM-WORLDSTANDARD code-look/syntax**

Also, I have friends who are C-as-an-assembly-type purists that just decided to learn JSEc(s)maScript[TM] completely from scratch (like they refuse to even view-source anywhere til then) as a race next Summer, and I'd be surprised if they don't do challenges here,

I know there's not a lot of us who post onobfuscated only under click to view hider "folds", but I only hang out here because there are so many people who end up being so creatively cool in different ways to each-others' differently-selected personal learningstyles.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you a language designer? That's coo. What language are you working on?