# How to avoid executing malicious obfuscated code?

Tags: discussion, testing

On a [related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/141/104) thread to this question, what steps can one take to avoid executing obfuscated malicious code (in the unlikely case someone sees fit to post some in a solution.

Is it best to just avoid testing code we don't understand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**On the one hand, it probably is.** Though some languages can be sandboxed, and you can test arbitrary programs if the sandbox is set up right, those languages are few and far in between, and security is a question of the "weakest link".

**On the other hand, it may not be necessary.** Posting malicious code violates section 3(e) of the [terms of service](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/legal), and moderators have the right to take adverse action against such users. Users (especially high-rep ones) usually do not want to jeopardise their hard-earned rep by engaging in such dubious actions.

Comment: "All my data's gone but *he* violated the TOS, boy is he screwed now!"

Comment: @Nick: I still maintain that some caution is wise. Indeed, my post did say so. I just think that it doesn't have to be a war zone.

Comment: @NickT jokes on you. He had his fingers crossed when checked the "I agree" button.

Answer (score 5):

I think the community will handle this. Its a non-issue.

If I saw malicious, or potentially malicious code I would:

- vote it down
- add a comment in all caps
- flag it.

(order might vary).

Comment: That would still harm your computer! :-(

Comment: @Metoniem, I think the point of this answer is that *someone* on this site will be able to recognize the code for what it is (malicious) without actually running it.  So if you're not sure, don't run it yourself — *especially* if it's a new answer and/or one with no upvotes yet.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to run everything from this site in a sandbox. [Here are some already available on the internet.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202/78)

Comment: I think this is the best solution. The are sandbox sites for many languages. In many cases it is easier to copy paste a solution into a text box and hit *Run*.