# Where to find an online testing environment for specific programming languages?

Tags: support, testing, faq-proposed

Here is my scenario.

1. I pose a programming puzzle. It might be golf, or might be something else, but I don't specify the language.
2. Some posts a answer that looks really good, but I don't have a working environment to test it.
3. ???
4. Profit!

Let us compile a list of free execution environments reachable over the internet.

One answer per answer, please, and list the protocol and host as well as as much detail on the available execution environments as possible.

Comment: Just now *I'm* looking for a ruby 1.9 shell.

Comment: I'd like to know where I can test windows powershell answers

Comment: @gnibbler, sandboxing powershell doesn't seem like an easy proposition.

Comment: also matlab or mathematica

Comment: ...anyone want to set up a VM? :)

Comment: @gnibbler: for matlab some of the answers should work with octave, which is free. For Mathematica there is Mathics, and it also has an online interpreter, but unfortunately that's not that feature-ready :(

Comment: The [There's a fiddle for that!](https://fiddles.io/) site currently lists 26 fiddle sites, some of those supporting multiple languages.

Answer (score 53):

## [Try It Online](https://tryitonline.net/)

[Try It Online](https://tryitonline.net/) has been created by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) and currently supports the following practical and recreational programming languages. (the snippet loads the current list)

```html
<h3>Practical</h3><div id="practical"><ul></ul></div><h3>Recreational</h3><div id="recreational"><ul></ul></div><script>var request=new XMLHttpRequest;request.open("GET","https://tio.run/languages.json"),request.onreadystatechange=function(){var languages,languageArray,id,language,i,item,anchor,j;if(request.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.DONE){languages=JSON.parse(request.response),languageArray=[];for(id in languages)language=languages[id],language.id=id,languageArray.push(language);for(languageArray.sort(function(languageA,languageB){return 2*(languageA.name.toLowerCase()>languageB.name.toLowerCase())-1}),i=0;i<languageArray.length;i++)for(language=languageArray[i],item=document.createElement("li"),anchor=document.createElement("a"),anchor.href="https://tio.run/#"+language.id,anchor.textContent=language.name,item.appendChild(anchor),j=0;j<language.categories.length;j++)document.getElementById(language.categories[j]).appendChild(item)}},request.send()</script>
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery to vastly simplify the GET request? It's already loaded by SE, so there won't be a noticeable performance hit, and the code would be significantly cleaner.

Comment: As it is, I can simply copy-paste the code from TIO's frontend. To take advantage of jQuery, I'd have to rewrite it. Also, I wouldn't consider anything that uses jQuery *clean*. :P

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null" running that snippet.

Answer (score 26):

[Ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com/) can compile/run over 40 languages, including Brainf**k and Whitespace.

List of supported languages:

- Ada
- Assembler
- Assembler
- AWK (gawk)
- AWK (mawk)
- Bash
- bc
- Brainf**k
- C
- C#
- C++
- C++0x
- C99 strict
- CLIPS
- Clojure
- COBOL
- COBOL 85
- Common Lisp (clisp)
- D (dmd)
- Erlang
- F#
- Factor
- Falcon
- Forth
- Fortran
- Go
- Groovy
- Haskell
- Icon
- Intercal
- Java
- JavaScript (rhino)
- JavaScript (spidermonkey)
- Lua
- Nemerle
- Nice
- Nimrod
- Objective-C
- Ocaml
- Octave
- Oz
- Pascal (fpc)
- Pascal (gpc)
- Perl
- Perl 6
- PHP
- Pike
- Prolog (gnu)
- Prolog (swi)
- Python
- Python 3
- R
- Ruby
- Scala
- Scheme (guile)
- Smalltalk
- SQL
- Tcl
- Text
- Unlambda
- Visual Basic .NET
- Whitespace

#### Pros & Cons:

- Pros:

  - support for many languages
  - you can store your program there, together with parameters/sample input
- Cons:

  - You have to obey some form and usage conventions to use IDEONE, like how to name your main-class in Scala.
  - The amount of CPU-time to run your program is limited

    - compilation time: 10 seconds,
    - execution time: 5 (by default and for not logged in users) or 15 seconds (this can be set from account settings page),
    - memory usage: 256 MB.
  - The version of the language used may be old (as is the case with R and Octave)
  - For more restrictions, see [the FAQ](http://www.ideone.com/faq) (Threads, Network, ...)

Comment: ...and integrate with my UserScript FTW!

Comment: They even have an API! This **has got** to be added to my script.

Comment: Nvm. I went with Codepad. IDEOne has usage limitations that could drastically affect the script.

Comment: Does Codepad have an API?

Comment: Codepad doesn't allow regex, though. At least not PCRE-style ones.

Comment: Ideone supports whitespace?! Weird..

Comment: There are also certain modules that don't work. Like Python's `turtle`.

Answer (score 18):

## [Attempt This Online](https://ato.pxeger.com/about)

<sup>*Note: I (pxeger) am the author and maintainer of ATO*</sup>

ATO was originally conceived as a replacement for the increasingly out-of-date Try It Online.

You can find it at **[`ato.pxeger.com`](https://ato.pxeger.com)**.

- It's completely free of charge
- The [software](https://github.com/attempt-this-online/attempt-this-online) is open-source (available under the copyleft [GNU Affero General Public License 3.0](https://github.com/attempt-this-online/attempt-this-online/blob/main/LICENCE.txt)
- We don't advertise or use any tracking technologies[*](https://ato.pxeger.com/legal#privacy-policy)
- Regularly maintained: new languages and features are added by request all the time
- The interface is [customisable](https://ato.pxeger.com/preferences)

There is an in-development version at [`staging.ato.pxeger.com`](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com) which generally follows the [tip of the `main` branch](https://github.com/attempt-this-online/attempt-this-online). If a language is newly added, it will be there for a while before appearing on the main version.

Comment: I guess there is no way to include wolfram as TIO has?

Answer (score 10):

Tutorials Point [Coding Ground](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm) has a ridiculous number of available IDEs and terminals. Some may require registration, some versions may be old/outdated.

Terminals:

- CentOS
- IPython
- Lua
- Memcached
- Mongo DB
- MySQL
- Node.JS
- Numpy
- Oracle
- Octave
- PowerShell
- PHP
- R Programming
- Redis
- Ruby
- Scipy
- Sympy

IDEs:

- Ada (Gnat)
- Algol-68
- Angular JS
- Assembly
- AsciiDoc
- Awk
- Bash Shell
- Befunge
- Bootstrap
- Brainfuck
- C
- CSS-3
- Clojure
- Cobol
- CoffeeScript
- C99 Strict
- C++
- C++ 0x
- C++ 11
- C#
- Dart
- D Language
- Embedded C
- Erlang
- Factor
- Fantom
- Falcon
- Fortran-95
- Forth
- F#
- Free Basic
- Groovy
- GO
- Haxe
- Haskell
- HTML
- ilasm
- Intercal
- ICON
- Java
- Java 8
- Java MySQL
- JavaScript
- Jquery
- Julia
- KSH Shell
- LaTeX
- Lisp
- LOLCODE
- Lua
- Matlab/Octave
- Malbolge
- Markdown
- MathML
- Mozart-OZ
- Node.JS
- Objective-C
- OCaml
- Pascal
- PARI/GP
- Pawn
- Perl
- Perl MySQL
- PHP
- PHP MySQL
- PHP Web View
- Processing.js
- P5.js
- Prolog
- Python
- Python-3
- Python MySQL
- Rexx
- reStructure
- Ruby
- Rust
- R Programming
- Scala
- Scheme
- Smalltalk
- SML/NJ
- Simula
- SQLite SQL
- Tcl
- Tex
- Unlambda
- VB.NET
- Verilog
- Whitespace

Comment: I can never get codingground to work.

Answer (score 9):

[codepad.org](http://codepad.org/) lets you paste code into a web interface and shows you the results. It compiles/interprets several languages: C, C++, D, Haskell, Lua, OCaml, PHP, Perl, Plain Text, Python, Ruby, Scheme, Tcl.

Comment: Codepad is now supported by my UserScript.

Answer (score 9):

### DataBot

Thanks to the work of myself ([Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941/mego)), [VoteToClose](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44713/votetoclose), [quartata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45151/quartata), and [CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/c-ob) (and building upon the [work](https://github.com/ProgramFOX/SE-Chatbot) of [ProgramFOX](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9275/programfox) et al.), a chat bot named [Data](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/49668/data) has been built that can run code for several different languages. Stop by the [PPCG Code Snippet Chat Bot room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35039/ppcg-code-snippet-chat-bot) to see it in action.

Languages supported:

- [All Try It Online! languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7840/45941)
- Pyth
- Marbelous
- Japt

If you want a language added to the bot, feel free to ask one of us in the chat room.

Comment: Note that this itself may also be considered a programming language in the near future.

Comment: This chat room has been frozen for inactivity.

Answer (score 8):

### Golfscript

http://golfscript.apphb.com/

This is a website that I built, due to the fact that there were no options for running GolfScript online.

Please note that it's experimental; if you notice any bugs, please let me know at golfscriptweb.feedback++@gmail.com.

#### Edit:

Please note that the script executes as if it were run from the command line with no arguments. This means that the stack already contains an empty string. If you need to test a script that takes arguments, do the following:

- use a semicolon (`;`) first, to pop the empty string off the stack.
- write the string containing the parameters
- write the script

Here is an example of a script that uses the string `arg` as a command line argument: http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OwonYXJnJwoKezJiYXNlfn0leyt9Kg==

#### Update 2012-10-25

New feature requested by [fjdumont](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5274/fjdumont) - hotkey for the ***Run*** button: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

#### Update 2013-02-20

Modified website design to make it a bit more usable on mobile devices.

Comment: how does one provide `stdin` input?

Comment: @boothby generally, in Golfscript you provide input as shown here: http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/tutorial.html (see the "input and output" section). In the website, you just discard the stack and then place a string on it. This behaves as if that string were read from STDIN

Comment: @boothby this example demonstrates a program that takes `5 5 1 3 3 5 2 4` as input from STDIN: http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyI1IDUgMSAzIDMgNSAyIDQiCgp%2BXTIvKFw6bTt%2BXDp3Kix7Wy53JSlcdy8pXTpebVw%2FKTQye217Xip%2BLS4qQEAtLiorMzx9LCw3Mm9yIDQ4K31pZn0ldy9uKg%3D%3D&run=true

Comment: I would love to see an accesskey for the `run` button... :)

Comment: I restarted the app and it's working again. My log does not contain anything suspicious; I'll need to see it's not logging that information.

Answer (score 8):

### APL

Note that "APL" is a rather vague term and a program written for one of these interpreters is unlikely to work with one of the others.

- [GNU APL](http://www.gnu.org/software/apl/)

  - Free software, runs on Linux. It's a bit sparse on features.
- [NARS2000](http://www.nars2000.org/)

  - Free software, runs on Windows. APL2-ish, has quite a bit of extra features.
- [Dyalog APL](http://www.dyalog.com)

  - Full-featured commercial software, but <s>by registering,</s> you <s>can</s> get a free non-commercial license for the latest version on any platform. <s>Alternatively, you can live with the pop-ups and nag screens of the unregistered version.</s> Has built-in GUI support, unlike any of the others.
- [TryAPL](http://tryapl.com/)

  - Runs in your browser, implements a large subset of Dyalog's newest version. Notably missing are most forms of I/O.
- [ngn/apl](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/)

  - Also runs in your browser. Dyalog 14... *ish*. (In fact, Dyalog 14 seems to have lifted some extensions from this.) Free (both kinds) implementation, but kind of quirky, for example `⎕IO` is stuck to `0` and it doesn't support `∇`-function definitions. Allows inline Javascript, for if you ever get the urge to write a web app in APL.
- [TIO](https://tio.run/#apl-dyalog)

  - Full session installation of Dyalog APL but stuck at version 17.1
- [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qsSAnPqUqMTM3ccGCpaUlaboWC5YUJyUXwzhQGgA)

  - Full shell script installation of the newest Dyalog APL.

**Additional options [listed on APL Wiki](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Running_APL).**

Comment: I think it should be noted that train parsing is different in ngn than Dyalog.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I actually spoke with ngn about that and he's implemented trains as atops now to match Dyalog's behavior.

Comment: @AlexA. Awesome; ngn's a lot more golfy then.

Answer (score 7):

I believe I now have a solution.

I have integrated [Codepad](http://codepad.org) support into my [UserScript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/). When using the script you will see:

[image]

**Notice the `[Run]` link on the right.** Clicking this will launch the code in Codepad and let you view the output. It's not perfect, and it's not a complete solution... but it works :)

**Note:** as of v0.35, you can even run code blocks in the markup preview as you're writing your answer.

Answer (score 6):

## [Do Stuff Online](https://dso.surge.sh)

DSO is an online interpreter service I made that runs entirely in your browser. It's a complete work in progress, and mostly runs JS-based languages although I've managed to get some Python-related stuff working too.

- Free to use
- Runs in your browser
- Dynamically loads interpreters from their sources for the latest version
- Doesn't have [an eight-page ToS](https://ato.pxeger.com/legal), or any ToS in fact. Mine all the cryptocurrency you want, it's your electricity.
- [Open-source](https://github.com/chunkybanana/do-stuff-online)
- Well-mantained, although there just aren't that many languages that can be used.

### Languages

- ngn/APL
- brainfuck
- BQN
- Deadfish + variants
- Fishing
- Halfwit
- Headass
- HQ9+ and variants
- in floop
- Japt
- K (oK)
- Pip
- Plumber
- Python 3
- Risky
- rSNBATWPL
- S10K
- ;#
- Tarfish
- Ultrarisky
- Unsure

Comment: Right, time to mine bitcoin and advertise raw tomatoes :P

Answer (score 5):

http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/ has interpreters for various languages:

- **FALSE**: http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/false-js.html
- **DUP**: http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html
- **SNUSP**: http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/
- **Befunge-93**: http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html
- **Brainfuck**: http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/bf.html
- **Biota**: http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/biota.html

  - "More Object Oriented": http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/biota-proto.html
- **Befalse**: http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befalse.html

Answer (score 5):

[alwaysdata.com](https://www.alwaysdata.com/features/frameworks/) has a free 10MB account and supports multiple versions of at least these

```
PHP
Python   2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.1
Ruby     1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.9.2
Perl     5.10
Java
Lua      5.1
OCaml
Erlang
```

Also many others that people have used for golfing, such as bash/sh/csh/ksh/tcsh/fish/zsh/dc

Answer (score 5):

[Replit](http://replit.com) is a free online interpreter/compiler I use for quite a few languages.

It can run:

- Ruby
- Python
- Python3
- C
- Java
- C++
- QBasic *
- CoffeeScript
- C#
- JavaScript
- LOLCODE

And more. Replit also supports using nix to build custom environments so you can now run pretty much any lanuguage.

<sub>* Note: The QBasic interpreter on Replit supports only a subset of QBasic. It usually can't handle golfed QBasic code.</sub>

Comment: It can also run Turtle and PyGame, for those who like Python

Answer (score 4):

## Virtualization

Perhaps obvious, but might be helpful.

Most languages have compilers/interpreters/emulators available for free download (google is your friend).  What may be harder is that those compilers/interpreters/emulators may only be available for a limited set of common OSes, for example bash on *nix or powershell on windows.  While many of us will have what I consider the three common OSes (Linux, OSX, Windows) available at all times, this is not necessarily a given.

One way around this is virtualization.  These days it is a simple matter to install a virtualization environment on your workstation of choice, and then install arbitrary OSes in VMs.

Common virtualization environments (some with free downloads) include:

- [VMWare Player (or fusion on OSX)](http://www.vmware.com/products/player)
- [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
- [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)
- several others

Then you'll need to find the OS to run in the VM.

- Linux is very easy to find.  [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) is often recommended for non-Linux users and IMO has a wealth of support information online
- Windows VMs for testing [are available here](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools)
- OSX.  Hmm, ok you'll need Apple hardware for that to comply with the EULA (even though recent OSX [can be installed in a VM](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2056603))

Answer (score 4):

## [Anarchy Golf](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

Anarchy Golf performance checker (link: http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb). It lets you run programs in those 111 languages:

(sorry, the list takes up quite a lot of screen space)

Most languages on Anarchy Golf are out of date, so it is worth checking the version on the page.

- ><>
- A+
- Ada
- Aheui
- Arc
- Asymptote
- AWK
- Bash
- Bash (builtins)
- BASIC
- bc
- Befunge
- Befunge-98
- Brainfuck
- Burlesque
- C
- C#
- C++
- Chapel
- CLC-INTERCAL
- Clojure
- COBOL
- Common LISP
- Crystal
- Curry
- Cyan
- D
- D-compile-time
- dc
- DOS
- Erlang
- Euphoria
- FerNANDo
- Fish
- FlogScript
- Forth
- Fortran
- gas
- gnuplot
- Go
- GolfScript
- goruby
- Grass
- Groovy
- gs2
- Haskell
- Hexagony
- Icon
- Io
- J
- Java
- JavaScript
- jq
- JVM
- K
- Kite
- Labyrinth
- Lazy-K
- LilyPond
- LMNtal
- Logo
- Lua
- m4
- make
- Malbolge
- Maxima
- Mind
- Minus
- MNNBFSL
- Nemerle
- ObjC
- OCaml
- Octave
- PARI/GP
- Pascal
- Pefunge
- Perl
- Perl6
- PHP
- Piet
- Pike
- Postscript
- Prolog
- Python
- Python3
- QCL
- R
- REBOL
- REXX
- Ruby
- Ruby2
- Rust
- Scala
- Scheme
- sed
- Smalltalk
- SNOBOL
- Squirrel
- Tcl
- Universal Lambda
- Unlambda
- VHDL
- Vim
- wake
- Whirl
- Whitespace
- x86
- xgawk
- Xtal
- z80
- Zsh

Answer (score 4):

## Rust

The [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) offers a nice editor with syntax highlighting and lets you choose between different compiler versions. You can also use the top 100 most downloaded crates from crates.io (like `chrono`, `serde` and `rand`).

Answer (score 3):

### http://tryruby.org/

Provides a version 1.9 interpreter, but they have disabled pasting into the text field, and there is no easy way to interact with the standard in-/out-put.

Comment: As the linked service [vanished more than an year ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/8we90r/what_happened_to_tryrubyorg/), the closest alternative seems to be https://ruby.github.io/TryRuby/

Answer (score 3):

## SQL (Including PL/SQL, T-SQL, MySQL, etc.)

While IdeOne may offer an SQL interpreter, to fully leverage SQL you need a database schema and a server to host it. Not to mention, ANSI SQL is more or less dead and every variant of the language has its own ways of implementing all the things that aren't covered in the standard.

That's where [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) comes in, with support for building a schema in a host environment and then querying against it.

Presently-available host environments:

- MySQL 5.5.32
- MySQL 5.6.6 m9
- MySQL 5.1.61
- Oracle 11g R2
- PostgreSQL 9.3.1
- PostgreSQL 9.2.4
- PostgreSQL 9.1.9
- PostgreSQL 8.4.17
- PostgreSQL 8.3.20
- SQLite (WebSQL)
- SQLite (SQL.js)
- MS SQL Server 2012
- MS SQL Server 2008

Very handy!

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple options for running [Piet](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Piet) online:

- The npiet interpreter has an [online version](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/npiet-execute.php). Upload an image file in ppm, png, or gif format.
- Try It Online can also run npiet. Because of TIO's text-only interface, you have to enter the program as a hexdump of an image file (ppm, png, or gif).

The [following website](http://www.rapapaing.com/blog/?page_id=6) used to provide an online IDE for Piet, but the link currently seems to be dead.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth

Online: https://pyth.herokuapp.com/

Download: https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth

Call with

```
python3 pyth.py <program>
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam

[Official Online Interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net) (cjam.aditsu.net).

Answer (score 3):

## [ESFiddle](http://vihan.org/p/esfiddle)

Not to be confused with ES6Fiddle. ESFiddle allows for running ES6 **and** ES7 *experimental features* such as array comprehension and the exponentiation operator which **no other** transpiler does.

[image: ESFiddle Screenshot]

ESFiddle also has syntax highlighting, and icons for `console.error` and `console.warn`. It also supports implicit output. You can even create permalinks to link to in your answers.

Answer (score 3):

### [glot.io](https://glot.io/)

is a free online pastebin that supports runnable online snippets.

It can run:

- Assembly
- ATS
- Bash
- C
- Clojure
- COBOL
- Coffeescript
- C++
- Crystal
- C#
- D
- Elixir
- Elm
- Erlang
- F#
- Go
- Groovy
- Haskell
- Idris
- Java
- Javascript
- Julia
- Kotlin
- Lua
- Mercury
- Nim
- Ocaml
- Perl
- Perl 6
- PHP
- Python
- Ruby
- Rust
- Scala
- Swift
- TypeScript

Comment: I feel like that list would look better as a single line.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate You might want to say that to [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14207/92069), [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7534/92069), [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8105/92069), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem with [pi-day golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440314/code-golf-day) on SO, the winning solution used the BSD variant of dc. Luckily I was able to confirm the answer on my silenceisdefeat.com which cost me $1. Seems to be dead now though. I guess I'll need to use a VM next time

EDIT: found the silenceisdefeat.com server has been upgraded and is now called saga.silenceisdefeat.net. Seems to be a quad core with 2GB ram

it has:
Python 2.4 2.5 2.6
Ruby 1.8.6
Perl 5.10.1

Answer (score 2):

[Simply Scala](http://www.simplyscala.com/) is a webinterface for interactive coding experience. A REPL (run-evaluate-print-loop).

You don't need to extend the App-class like in IDEONE.

Answer (score 2):

**Burlesque** has on online shell [here](http://cheap.int-e.eu/~burlesque/burlesque.cgi)
The interpreter can also be downloaded on the official [webpage](http://mroman.ch/burlesque) and installed locally.

Answer (score 2):

### Codio

https://codio.com/ offers free Ubuntu virtual machines accessible in the browser.
The following languages are available out of the box:

- JavaScript (node)
- Ruby 2.1.5
- Python 2.7.3
- Perl 5
- Java 1.7

It's possible to install a lot of other languages/platforms, for example:

- C# (Mono)
- PHP

Answer (score 2):

## R

- [R-Fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org)
- [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) -- uses a *very* old version
- [Coding Ground](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php)

## Julia

- [JuliaBox](http://www.juliabox.org) -- requires a Google account
- [Coding Ground](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_julia_online.php) -- uses an old version

It's good to note that, at least for me, Coding Ground rarely works.

Answer (score 2):

## Rollapp

You can use **Rollapp** for text editors like emacs, brackets, and there are some IDEs in the 'coming soon' section. It does not support sharing very well, but if you are looking to run other people's code the IDEs may work when they come out (or if they come out). Hopefully they will make Eclipse available and we will have a full java IDE on the web!!

links:
https://www.rollapp.com/app/terminator - run bash and perl etc
https://www.rollapp.com/app/eclipse - eclipse, hopefully will work soon

Answer (score 2):

## [Making Future Posts Runnable Online with Stack Snippets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40073/making-future-posts-runnable-online-with-stack-snippets/66033)

Has interpreters for a lot of esoteric languages.

## [Labyrinth](http://output.jsbin.com/cuzoxu)

That is a Labyrinth interpreter I wrote. (It doesn't support bigintegers yet.)
It has a fairly useful debug feature that allows you to see the pointer moving around.

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

- https://jqplay.org ­– Not written by the language's developer himself, but the official [jq Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) also uses it to run its examples.

  <s>jq play is more an interactive playground, so the checkboxes to emulate the command line switches not seem to be settable through GET parameters, like the **Filter** (`q` parameter) and **JSON** (`j` parameter) inputs can be.</s> (They fixed it. Now it can generate a permalink with the complete setup.)
- https://jqterm.com/ – “an alternative interactive jq web terminal with autocomplete (and faster querying with large datasets as they're cached online in private gists).” (According to [jq recipes](https://remysharp.com/drafts/jq-recipes)).

Answer (score 2):

## [QBasic 1.1 at Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack)

Real QBasic--sound, graphics, everything--running in DOSBox, available in your browser. Caveats: there's no copy-and-paste, so you have to type your code by hand, and I haven't found a way to break out of infinite loops (short of closing the browser and starting a new session).

Answer (score 1):

## [Chicken](http://torso.me/chicken)

The language's homepage has an interpreter built-in.

Answer (score 1):

## [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

If most of the time, I will use Tio for .NET snippet. It is good to know about [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/).

- .NETFiddle supports C#, F# and VB.
- .NETFiddle compiles with .NET 4.5 or Roslyn 2.0
- .NETFiddle allows to use NuGet Packages **!**

Answer (score 1):

### [Wren](http://wren.io/)

There is an online interpreter for Wren called ["the Wren Nest"](http://ppvk.github.io/wren-nest/).

Answer (score 1):

## [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/)

Scastie is a free, no-account-required sandbox for running Scala code. It's particularly good for testing short snippets, since code doesn't need to be contained in a class/object or method. In worksheet mode, when a snippet is executed, each expression's value and type are displayed next to it; you can also use `print` and related functions to output to the console as usual. Scastie generates permalinks ([like so](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/u1hSrP02Tn6EdEqfk6bXMQ)) and supports both Scala 2 and Scala 3. You can also sign in to Scastie using your GitHub account so you can access your saved links more easily.

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke

Online: [pyke.catbus.co.uk](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk)

Answer (score 0):

## CGL (CGL Golfing Language)

[There is a CodePen online interpreter for it.](https://codepen.io/programmer5000/pen/zwYrVd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Fourier](http://beta-decay.github.io/editor)

Whilst also available on http://tryitonline.net, the full version of Fourier (with delays and screen clearing) can be found permanantly on http://beta-decay.github.io/editor.